# Does the iOS version have Survival mode?

Tags: ios, plants-vs-zombies, version-differences

I'd already been all the way through PvZ on my iPhone before the zen garden upgrade. I've continued playing, farming coins to unlock minigames, etc. However, the game seems to have entirely stopped giving me new plants. I've resorted to buying them expensively from the new store options.

[How do I get more plants for my Zen Garden?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/14737/how-do-i-get-more-plants-for-my-zen-garden) talks about 'survival' mode, but I don't see that anywhere on my phone. Does it have some other name, or is it not in the mobile version?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

New plants are given out randomly, so sometimes it will take a while to get one. You can only receive a plant if you have space for it in the main garden (regardless of how much space you have in the mushroom/aquatic gardens).

Also in my experience, the game seems to favour giving you chocolate for Stinky the Snail first. Try keeping the chocolate until you have 10 (the maximum) and perhaps you will gain more plants.

There is no survival mode in the iOS version yet, but they seem to add new features (more mini-games, puzzle mode) from the other versions every few months, so it may be added eventually.

If you want to play a mode with lots of zombies (to increase chances of getting a ZG plant) then I'd recommend playing the *Last Stand* or *Column Like You See 'Em* mini-games.

Comment: I'm somewhat dubious of them ever adding in Survival mode due to the nature of the iDevice game having the options to buy more coins and purchase ZG plants in the shop. Most people used the Survival mode for farming both plants and coins. Adding in a mode that takes away from their revenue stream runs counter to the business practices I've come to expect out of EA these days.

Comment: @TechParadox I never said they'd add it for free, probably a paid upgrade rather than coins. Also note there are plenty of ways to farm coins as it is (e.g. Last Stand).

Comment: I never said that you did say they'd add it in - I was just remarking that despite their history of adding in new features with updates I doubt that they'd add a mode that would basically be shooting their revenue stream in the foot. :) I personally have had good luck farming coins via the quick play version of 1-1. With a good setup you can rake in around 4500 a round. I'll have to give Last Stand a try once I get it unlocked.

Answer (score 4):

Survival Mode is in the iPad version of Plants vs. Zombies, but it's missing from the iPhone and iPod Touch versions ([source](http://plantsvszombies.wikia.com/wiki/Survival_Mode)). It's possible that it will be added in, though, because PopCap has a history of very gradually updating the mobile version of their games.