# I finished Plants Vs Zombies but I didn't get the trophy or unlock Survival?

Tags: ios, plants-vs-zombies

I want to play Survival but it didn't unlock when I killed Dr. Zomboss. Do I need to do adventure mode again or something else?

I've tried to do it on another account but that didn't work either.

Comment: [Related](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/45879/73976)

Answer (score -1):

Sounds like either a glitch or the ios version does not have them.