# Why can't I progress in Zen Garden

Tags: pc, plants-vs-zombies

I have finish all the levels twice, I almost finished all the achievements. How come I can't get any other plants for my Zen Garden other than the white plants? I can't get a snail, chocolate, under water Zen Garden or the Mushroom Zen garden.
I have done everything on this game that can make me achieve this.

Please help. One of the achievements are to collect all the Zen Garden plants in all your Zen Gardens. I can't achieve this achievement due to above mentioned issue. It's not life or death, but I get just a little obsessive.

Comment: Does anything in this question help: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/14737/how-do-i-get-more-plants-for-my-zen-garden?rq=1

Comment: Do you not know *how* to get these things, or are you actually unable to get them? (Apart from the plants and the chocolate) these items need to be purchased from the shop

Answer (score 5):

You have to keep playing the different modes like puzzle, adventure, survival ect...

Plants for the zen garden are rare drops so you need to play and play and play

Also in the shop there should be three plants on sale everyday that are different to the plants on the previous day in my experience but I had to buy them for the next days plants to be different